# Python: Coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python, websocket, coroutine

I'm using await to then send a websocket message when connected but it keeps giving me "was never awaited" and doesn't send and I've tried to add `await` to the `.send()` function like this answer below asks me to, however it throws a TypeError: data is a dict-like object.

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

logging.basicConfig()
IPAddress = input("Configure IP Address")
Port = input("Configure Port")
P1_UserID = ""
P2_UserID = ""
USERS = set()

async def register_player(websocket):
    global P1_UserID, P2_UserID
    if not P1_UserID:
        P1_UserID = websocket
        P1_UserID.send({"Player": 1})
    elif not P2_UserID:
        P2_UserID = websocket
        P2_UserID.send({"Player": 2})
    print(P1_UserID)
    print(P2_UserID)


async def server(websocket, path):
    await register(websocket)
    try:
        await register_player(websocket)
        async for e in websocket:
            print(e)
    finally:
        pass


start_server = websockets.serve(server, IPAddress, Port)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code that is not relevant to the problem, please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for future reference.

Comment: Please also post the exact error message and traceback if available which helps to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `websockets` module [documentation](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#basic-example), it seems like you must `await` on `websocket.send()`.

However, in your `register_player()` function, where you assign `P1_UserID = websocket`, you don't `await` on `send()` in the line below.

Apart from that, the `message` passed to `websocket.send()` cannot be a `dict`, see [here](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/server.html#websockets.server.WebSocketServerProtocol.send).

Try changing `register_player()` to the following:

```py
async def register_player(websocket):
    global P1_UserID, P2_UserID

    if not P1_UserID:
        P1_UserID = websocket
        await P1_UserID.send(json.dumps({"Player": 1}))
#       ^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^
#       This is missing      The message cannot be a
#       in your code.        dict, hence convert it to str.
    elif not P2_UserID:
        P2_UserID = websocket
        await P2_UserID.send(json.dumps({"Player": 2}))
#       ^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^
#       Same as above.       Same as above.
```

Comment: I tried doing that, unfortunately it gives TypeError: data is a dict-like object

Comment: @JoySingh - Could you please post the exact error message and the traceback?

Comment: I've updated the answer, `websocket.send()` doesn't accept `dict`s.

Comment: :') Thank you so much. I literally don't know much python and I'm trying to create a server using python lol.

Comment: @JoySingh - I'm glad to hear and no worries! My suggestion is to always read the documentation even when it's tough in the beginning. You can learn a lot from it. Good luck!